# Microsoft Web Infrastructure server error

Tags: visual-studio

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' or one of its dependencies. The located
> assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) Description: An unhandled
> exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
> where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' or one of its dependencies.
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
> determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' could not be
> loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
> failure logging, set the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
> is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
> logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +232
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +113
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +23
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +762
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +259
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +167
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +238
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +78
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +178
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +746

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +732
```

I need help on solving this problem. I've been trying to solve this problem for several days.